# How can I check if a string contains ANY letters from the alphabet?

Tags: python, string

What is best pure Python implementation to check if a string contains ANY letters from the alphabet?

```
string_1 = "(555).555-5555"
string_2 = "(555) 555 - 5555 ext. 5555
```

Where `string_1` would return `False` for having no letters of the alphabet in it and `string_2` would return `True` for having letter.

Comment: Should this be limited to english a/z alphabet only ? Should 'special' characters from others alphabets, like German, be taken in account ?

Comment: Is there any chance that you will receive unicode? Or just plain ascii roman letters?

Comment: Nice timing there :) Anyway, check this similar question out if you need help testing strings with unicode characters.

Comment: Limited to English a/z alphabet only and only plain ascii roman letters :)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Regex should be a fast approach:

```
re.search('[a-zA-Z]', the_string)
```

Comment: Thank you JBernado, this is what I ended up doing and it works flawlessly for what I need to do.

Comment: Regex certainly seems a bit overkill. `any(c.isalpha() for c in string_1)` is deliciously Pythonic.

Comment: @Joseph No, it is not. This regex is far more readable than your expression. Also, what does `isalpha` even means? This will have totally different behaviors when comparing Python 2 with Python 3. Is Chinese part of the alphabet? If not, you are blindly matching it with your generator on Python 3  (Or Python 2 for unicode strings!). If you want *Pythonic*, here it is: `Simple is better than complex.`. And check OP's comment above: He wants only the roman alphabet to be matched.

Comment: I think Joseph's answer is perfectly readable and it's certainly faster than an additional import; plus you don't have to remember the order of arguments in re.search

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering what the return value is, you get a `Match` object if there is a match, or `None` if there isn't. So this is compatible with a `if re.search(...` pattern.

Comment: For `a_long_string` of length 50 (an alpha at the end), 
`%timeit -n 1000000 any(c.isalpha() for c in a_long_string)`
`1000000 loops, best of 3: 4.99 µs per loop`
`%timeit -n 1000000 re.search("[a-zA-Z]", a_long_string)`
`1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 µs per loop`
The results speak for themselves.

Comment: @JBernardo Why do you keep removing the import? It's important for people to know what libraries they need to import.

Comment: @JoshCorreia Every time you see `something.other_thing` you know you need to import something. No need to add clutter. Your change was rejected 3 times by other reviewers and I also rejected such changes in the past. Since this is a very old answer, unless there is something intrinsically wrong after that long period, it shouldn't be changed for trivialities.

Comment: @JBernardo Knowing from which module to import is not a triviality. It should be at least mentioned. Import Regular Expression Operation from `re` module (Python 2.7 to 3.9.5).

Comment: unlike the accepted answer `isalpha()` will properly detect non-English alphabets; the correct regex to match any unicode text would be `re.search('\w', the_string)` (but also more expensive)

Answer (score 112):

How about:

```
>>> string_1 = "(555).555-5555"
>>> string_2 = "(555) 555 - 5555 ext. 5555"
>>> any(c.isalpha() for c in string_1)
False
>>> any(c.isalpha() for c in string_2)
True
```

Comment: Would `set(string_1)` be more efficent?

Comment: @Rik. You mean converting string_1 to a set before testing it? No it won't be more efficient. That is guaranteed to deal with all characters at least once while I believe the any function will short circuit (stop) when it encounters the first false.

Comment: This code will be somewhat slow because it requires a function call per char. Converting to `set` may or may not reduce function calls, but adds some overhead.

Comment: @JBernardo: timeit suggests it's about an order of magnitude slower than a compiled regex and takes only about 66% more time than a non-compiled one.  That's well within my "I hate regular expressions" limits.

Comment: I don't know how big can be the strings but function calls are always expensive (Functions written in C, like `str.isalpha`, are quite faster to be called thought).

Comment: On big strings, using `string_1 = "(555).555-5555"*1000`, regex is 17 times faster here. (Of course this is the worst case)

Comment: Sure: and if you use "(555).555-5555 ext. 5555"*1000 you're back to comparable speeds because of the short-circuiting.  I much prefer writing in Python to writing regular expressions, which I find hard to debug unless they're trivial, and I'm not going to give up on writing clear Python unless performance requirements demand it.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's input/thoughts/help/answers.

Answer (score 30):

You can use `islower()` on your string to see if it contains some lowercase letters (amongst other characters). `or` it with `isupper()` to also check if contains some uppercase letters:

below: letters in the string: test yields true

```
>>> z = "(555) 555 - 5555 ext. 5555"
>>> z.isupper() or z.islower()
True
```

below: no letters in the string: test yields false.

```
>>> z= "(555).555-5555"
>>> z.isupper() or z.islower()
False
>>>
```

Not to be mixed up with `isalpha()` which returns `True` only if all characters are letters, which isn't what you want.

Note that [Barm's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47453486/5337834) answer completes mine nicely, since mine doesn't handle the mixed case well.

Comment: I like that this will test if it CONTAINS letters, not just test if input is ALL letters.

Comment: @Cornbeetle yes, that kind of really answers the question after all those years, thanks

Comment: Very nice way to put this. How is it in terms of efficiency ? better than regex?

Comment: there are no python loops involved, so the efficiency is good. I didn't compare with regex but I suppose it's slightly faster, specially for the initialization phase because there's no regex to compile

Comment: How would this work? This only works if all the characters in the string are either upper or lower. This does not solve the problem if there are mixed...

Comment: doesn't handle mixed case, that's stated in the answer

Answer (score 20):

I liked the answer provided by [@jean-françois-fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43002960/5337834), but it is incomplete.
His approach will work, but only if the text contains purely lower- or uppercase letters:

```
>>> text = "(555).555-5555 extA. 5555"
>>> text.islower()
False
>>> text.isupper()
False
```

The better approach is to first upper- or lowercase your string and then check.

```
>>> string1 = "(555).555-5555 extA. 5555"
>>> string2 = '555 (234) - 123.32   21'

>>> string1.upper().isupper()
True
>>> string2.upper().isupper()
False
```

Answer (score 13):

I tested each of the above methods for finding if any alphabets are contained in a given string and found out average processing time per string on a standard computer.


~250 ns for

```
import re
```

~3 µs for

```
re.search('[a-zA-Z]', string)
```

~6 µs for

```
any(c.isalpha() for c in string)
```

~850 ns for

```
string.upper().isupper()
```

Opposite to as alleged, importing *re* takes negligible time, and searching with *re* takes just **about half time** as compared to iterating *isalpha()* even for a relatively small string.

Hence for larger strings and greater counts, re would be significantly more efficient.


But converting string to a case and checking case (i.e. any of *upper().isupper()* or *lower().islower()* ) **wins** here. In every loop it is significantly faster than *re.search()* and it doesn't even require any additional imports.

Comment: You can also compile the regex for furhter optimization.
alpha_regex = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]')

later
alpha_regex.search(string)

Comment: Not to mention isalpha() doesn't workout well for multi languages. I was looking for this because I wanted to check whether a string that is expected to be Korean contains any English letters and the isalpha() method returns True for every korean string.

Answer (score 11):

You can use regular expression like this:

```
import re

print re.search('[a-zA-Z]+',string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in addition

```
import re
string='24234ww'
val = re.search('[a-zA-Z]+',string) 
val[0].isalpha() # returns True if the variable is an alphabet
print(val[0]) # this will print the first instance of the matching value
```

Also note that if variable *val* returns None. That means the search did not find a **match**