# Python How to check if user input is a string?

Tags: string, python-2.7, types, typechecking

My first question on here...

I want to know how to check if the user input is a string.  If it is not a message should appear.  Otherwise the answer should be accepted.  Here is what I have (I am looking for the simplest fix please):

```
try:
    name=str(raw_input("What is your name? "))
except:
    print("Your name must consist of letters only")
else:
    print("Thank you for entering your name.")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string contains ANY letters from the alphabet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072844/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-any-letters-from-the-alphabet)

Comment: Here is something interesting to read if you want to validate names: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: `raw_input` always returns a string, so you don't have to do anything ;-) did you mean to ask "how to check if user input contains only alphabetical characters"?

Answer (score 3):

`str.isalpha()` checks if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character. So

```
name=str(raw_input("What is your name? "))
if not name.isalpha():
    print("Your name must consist of letters only")
else:
    print("Thank you for entering your name.")
```

*However this will not work if `name` is "Homer Simpson" (with a space)* which is valid input for `name`.

And don't you forget [this](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)!!!

Answer (score 1):

What about an assertion with the check for non ascii letters in the string , similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number),

```
import string
try:
    name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    assert  any([char not in string.ascii_letters for char in name]) is False
except AssertionError:
    print("Your name must consist of letters only")
else:
    print("Thank you for entering your name.")
```

Comment: Ok, now how do you check for characters that aren't letters or digits, such as "~"?

Comment: What if `name` contains `,` or `&`?

Comment: Good point, I assumed string would want anything but numbers. I've changed to check for all ascii letters. If the name had an accent, etc this may need to be expanded (e.g. using `string.printable` instead of `string.ascii_letters`).