# how to check if the is any char (a - b) in string

Tags: python

i am trying to chek if certain string contain any char from the a - z. 
I saw that i can use in `in` but it not seem to be the most comfortable Way to pass all over the string like that:

```
if a in string
if b in string
if c in string
```

Can you help me to find function/algorithm are doing it? will it work on numbers as well?

Comment: have you looked into the `re` module in python? https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html You can construct regular expressions and then search in a string for the pattern.

Comment: Borrowing from [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9072862/10077) in the duplicate, try `any(c.islower() for c in str)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try use regex by

```
import re
If re.search(r"[a-z]", s):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

convert your input strings to lists then post process like this:

```
list(set([x for x in a if x in b]))
```

script:

```
STRING = ";alkd779-n;l--xswdlfkj"
TEST = "abcde"

string = list(STRING)
test = list(TEST)
matches =  list(set([x for x in string if x in test]))
contains_match = True if len(matches)>0 else False

print 'string         : %s' % string
print 'test           : %s' % test
print 'matches        : %s' % matches 
print 'contains match : %s' % contains_match

>>>
string         : [';', 'a', 'l', 'k', 'd', '7', '7', '9', '-', 'n', ';', 'l', '-', '-', 'x', 's', 'w', 'd', 'l', 'f', 'k', 'j']
test           : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
matches        : ['a', 'd']
contains match : True
```

Comment: i want to try it without for loop (that the idea i guess thanks).so why to use in 'set' function in this algoritem?

Comment: set removes duplicates

Comment: for moves item by item from string list to matches list if item exists in the test list