# How to test if a string has capital letters

Tags: python, string

In Scala I could test if a string has a capital letter like this:

```
val nameHasUpperCase = name.exists(_.isUpper)
```

The most comprehensive form in Python I can think of is:

```
a ='asdFggg'
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x or y, [c.isupper() for c in a])
->True
```

Somewhat clumsy. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string contains ANY letters from the alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072844/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-any-letters-from-the-alphabet)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest to the Scala statement is probably an `any(..)` statement here:

```
any(x.isupper() for x in a)
```

This will work in using a generator: from the moment such element is found, `any(..)` will stop and return `True`.

This produces:

```
>>> a ='asdFggg'
>>> any(x.isupper() for x in a)
True
```

Or another one with `map(..)`:

```
any(map(str.isupper,a))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this would be comparing the original string to it being completely lower case:

```
>>> a ='asdFggg'
>>> a == a.lower()
False
```

And if you want this to return true, then use `!=` instead of `==`

Comment: this will certainly work, but it creates a new string (`a.lower`), which Willem's will avoid by using a generator

Comment: @JasonStein totally agree, just thought i'd show another way of doing it :)

Answer (score 2):

There is also

```
nameHasUpperCase = bool(re.search(r'[A-Z]', name))
```