# Efficient way to mount a list of word occurences on Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I want to mount a data structure stating the number of occurences and mapping them at the right order.

For example:

> word_1 => 10 occurences
>
> word_2 => 5 occurences
>
> word_3 => 12 occurences
>
> word_4 => 2 ocurrences

and each word has one id to represent it:

```
kw2id = ['word_1':0, 'word_2':1, 'word_3':2, 'word_4': 3]
```

so an ordered list would be:

```
ordered_vocab = [2, 0, 1, 3]
```

For instance my code is this...:

```
#build a vocabulary with the number of ocorrences
vocab = {}
count = 0
for line in open(DATASET_FILE):
    for word in line.split():
        if word in vocab:
            vocab[word] += 1
        else:
            vocab[word] = 1
    count += 1
    if not count % 100000:
        print(count, "documents processed")
```

How can I do this **efficiently**?

Comment: So, how are the occurrences stored? I am guessing that's one of the inputs. Could you clearly define the sample inputs?

Comment: why not using `collections.Counter` and then sort the keys with some rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [**`Counters`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) were made for:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()

with open(DATASET_FILE) as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        for word in line.split():
            cnt[word] += 1
```

Or (shorter and more "beautiful" using a generator):

```
from collections import Counter

with open(DATASET_FILE) as fp:
    words = (word for line in fp.readlines() for word in line.split())
    cnt = Counter(words)
```

Comment: How can I print for example.. the 3 top words of the Counter obj?

Comment: Nvm, just use an iteration... Thanks a lot, this solve the problem.

Comment: @denisCandido: You're welcome.

Comment: but in that case that's a triplicate answered a zillion times... I found 3 Q&A in 2 minutes with the same stuff.

Comment: ce n'est pas le but ultime. if you already seen such a question or a simple google search finds 3 hits, you just shouldn't answer (or flag as dupes & answer in the original questions if your answer is different/better/more up to date). Doesn't work everytime, but sometimes it does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072844/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-any-letters-from-the-alphabet/43002960#43002960

Comment: Sorry but I used the search and didn't found any question like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly faster version of your code, I'm sorry I don't know numpy very well, but maybe this will help, `enumerate` and `defaultdict(int)` are the changes I have made (you do not have to accept this answer, just trying to help)

```
from collections import defaultdict

#build a vocabulary with the number of ocorrences
vocab = defaultdict(int)
with open(DATASET_FILE) as file_handle:
    for count,line in enumerate(file_handle):
        for word in line.split():
            vocab[word] += 1
        if not count % 100000:
            print(count, "documents processed")
```

Also `defaultdict(int)` when starting from 0 appears to be twice as fast as `Counter()` for an increment in a for loop (running Python 3.44):

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
import time

words = " ".join(["word_"+str(x) for x in range(100)])
lines = [words for i in range(100000)]

counter_dict = Counter()
default_dict = defaultdict(int)

start = time.time()
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():
        counter_dict[word] += 1
end = time.time()
print (end-start)

start = time.time()
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():
        default_dict[word] += 1
end = time.time()
print (end-start)
```

results:

```
5.353034019470215
2.554084062576294
```

If you would like to dispute this claim I refer you to this question: [Surprising results with Python timeit: Counter() vs defaultdict() vs dict()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801945/surprising-results-with-python-timeit-counter-vs-defaultdict-vs-dict)

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection.Counter. Counter allows you to input a list and it will automatically count the number of occurrences of each element.

```
from collections import Counter
l = [1,2,2,3,3,3]
cnt = Counter(l)
```

So what you can do, besides the above answer, it to create a list of words out of the file, and use Counter with a list instead of iterating through each element in the list manually. Note that this method is not suitable if your file is too big compared to your memory.

Answer (score 0):

The String:

```
>>> a = 'word_1 word_2 word_3 word_2 word_4'
```

The IDs

```
>>> d = {'word_1':0, 'word_2':1, 'word_3':2, 'word_4': 3}
```

To generate word counts:

```
>>> s = dict(zip(a.split(), map(lambda x: a.split().count(x), a.split())))
>>> s
{'word_1': 1, 'word_2': 2, 'word_3': 1, 'word_4': 1}
```

To generate ordered list:

```
>>> a = sorted(s.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> ordered_list = list(map(lambda x: d[x[0]], a ))
>>> ordered_list
[1, 0, 2, 3]
```