# tokenize words, delete punctuaction using nltk

Tags: python

this is an example of how I am tokenizing a phrase for my language that is Spanish.

```
texto= "esto es un texto, para el sr. gómez. Esto; es una prueba que puedes encontrar en www.google.com quisiera encontrarla.. claro esta,.Quisiera mejorarlo"
```

when I use nltk that tokenizes my phrase, this is the output:

```
['esto', 'es', 'un', 'texto', ',', 'para', 'el', 'sr.', 'gómez', '.', 'Esto', ';', 'es', 'una', 'prueba', 'que', 'puedes', 'encontrar', 'en', 'www.google.com','quiero','encontarla..','esta,.', 'quisiera','mejoralo']
```

how can I eliminate the punctuation except for valid scores like `sr.` or `www.google.com`

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
texto= "esto es un texto, para el sr. gómez. Esto; es una prueba que puedes encontrar en www.google.com quisiera encontrarla.."
palabras_tokenizadas=(word_tokenize(texto,"spanish"))
print(palabras_tokenizadas)
```

this should be the result:

```
['esto', 'es', 'un', 'texto',  'para', 'el', 'sr.', 'gómez',  'Esto',  'es', 'una', 'prueba', 'que', 'puedes', 'encontrar', 'en', 'www.google.com', 'quisiera', 'encontrarla', 'claro', 'esta', 'quisiera', 'mejorarlo']
```

I tried something like this, but it does not solve my problem (problem with words like`"encontarla.."`, `"esta,."`

```
punctuation = [",", ";", ".",...............] # The tokens that I want to skip
palabras_tokenizadas_1 = [ palabra for palabra in palabras_tokenizadas if palabra not in punctuation ]
```

I would like to make the best way to solve my problem globally in any sentence that has a score, not just fix the problem to this sentence. How can do it?

Comment: Should numbers be included or excluded? `'1995'` for example.

Comment: included, I think that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
res = [tkn for tkn in tkn_lst if tkn.lower().islower() or any(chr.isdigit() for chr in tkn)]
```

- `tkn.lower().islower()` checks whether [any letters are in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47453486/3579910)
- `any(chr.isdigit()...)` allows for strings that have numbers but no letters

Combined they require each token to contain some alphanumeric part, although if I was using this I'd make it more readable via a helper function:

```
def has_alphanum(token):
    return token.lower().islower() or any(character.isdigit() for character in token)

res = [token for token in palabras_tokenizadas1 if has_alphanum(token)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to use your code, when I went to implement it I have problems.  s="esto es un texto, para el sr. gómez. Esto; es una prueba que puedes encontrar en www.google.com quisiera encontrarla.." look please the output. Thanks

Comment: @unusuario The input should be `palabras_tokenizadas1` (a token list), not a string.

Comment: def has_alphanum(str):
    return token.lower().islower() or any(character.isdigit() for character in token)
palabras_tokenizadas=['esto', 'es', 'un', 'texto', ',', 'para', 'el', 'sr.', 'gómez', '.', 'Esto', ';', 'es', 'una', 'prueba', 'que', 'puedes', 'encontrar', 'en', 'www.google.com','quiero','encontarla..']
res = [token for token in palabras_tokenizadas if has_alphanum(token)] this not works for me...islower() or any(character.isdigit() for character in token)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable) Will this work with my last word? I have updated the question so that you understand

Comment: @unusuario Not sure why it's giving you an exception. It [works on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FailingTechnologicalTasks).

Comment: ohh... look the ultimate word please

Comment: @unusuario that doesn't really fit the original question: how do I know I should remove that punctuation but not `sr.`? You'd have to figure out a way of delineating the two and write a special case.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do with a punctuation list:

```
punctuation = [",", ";", "."] # The tokens that you want to skip
palabras_tokenizadas2 = [ palabra for palabra in palabras_tokenizadas1 if palabra not in punctuation ]
```

The output:

```
['esto', 'es', 'un', 'texto', 'para', 'el', 'sr.', 'gómez', 'Esto', 'es', 'una', 'prueba', 'que', 'puedes', 'encontrar', 'en', 'www.google.com']
```

For all punctuation marks you can check `string.punctuation` and use like this:

```
import string
punctuation = list(string.punctuation)
```

The output:

```
['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. in the case of "www.google.com" and "sr." will eliminate the punctuation

Comment: @unusuario should not. If the output of simple tokenizing is what you post at the beginning this method will not remove the '.' from "sr." or "www.google.com". That's because you are doing a comparation between words and not at character level.

Comment: ohh you're right, I thought there would be a smarter way to get it with the library. excuse me

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this does not work well for the last word, please look at the output.

Comment: @unusuario That's not the problem you exposed at the question. There is a mistake on the sentence and the tokenizer could not deal with it. My solution will not work with that, because this is another problem completely different.

Comment: I think I did not make myself understood, but can you think of something to solve it? the nltk tokenizer returns my phrase that way