# Python program to check if the word has an alphabet lowercase letter or not

Tags: python

I was trying to make a `program` to check if word has an alphabet letter in it or no, but when it runs it displays all the letters because of `for loop` so is there any other code I can use to make the program?

**Here's my code:**

```
import string


def checker(word):
    lower = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

for char in lower:
    if char in word:
        print("Word has alphabet lowercase letter.")
    else:
        print("Error")
return word


wordy = input("Enter: ")
word_ = checker(wordy)
```

Comment: You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072844/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-any-letters-from-the-alphabet) question

Comment: `isalpha` is an inbuilt function. you can use that here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Try the code below and let me know if it meets your needs

```
 words= input("enter any word ?")

 for word in words:
     if word.isalpha():
         print("True")
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
import re   

def checker(word): 
    match = re.search('[a-zA-Z]', word)
    if match is not None:
       return True
    return False

checker('10')
# False
checker('aaa')
# True
```